# E-Mail form to users based on role

Tags: php, wordpress, email, role

So I'm having a problem with a form I've made so one user can e-mail other users based on role `fans` , `players` or the `admin`.

Comment: it would be useful to know what the problem is... :|

Comment: Yeah... I was typing it as you were typing this. Apologies!

Comment: it is an apache 500 error? (500 "Internal Server Error")

Comment: Yes! Sorry, didn't think to include that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

500 "Internal Server Error":

Documentation:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/http-error-500-internal-server-for-php-pages-and-solution.html (first page on google...)

You may be getting that error because of a .htacces file that is being "disturbed" by your code :) . But is generally caused by the php settings on your server. Check the integrity of the php (.ini) files on the system and search for any file that might be missing or incomplete.

***EDIT:***

Because you get an error when mailing.... check the part of your system php files (.ini) that are related to that.

Comment: I've got an error log, but it's not logging that error. Any other page it does.

Comment: the 500 error isn't logged...read the post in the link....the problem is generated by php itself not by your code (also by your code but not because of it's syntax) (it isn't an syntax error code)

Comment: Thank you for your help! Although I never found the actual problem, your input sent me down the rabbit hole for finding the right answer. I just put the PHP after the form on the same page, but set it to run on the $_POST['submit'] condition. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The two files are located in the same folder? 
In order to debug if the file is working you can "echo" a dummy content at the beginning of the file to test that you are going to that file (echo "worked";), then you can echo your $_POST data and check it, maybe you must check if $_POST is set : if( (isset($_POST)) AND (isset($_POST['user_name'])) ){}

Comment: Yes, they're in the same folder. However, the 500 error comes when I send, so it never echoes anything.

Comment: Maybe you can try using mail function it is well documented, instead of wp_mail:

http://php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php